# How to CREATE TEMP TABLE with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, locking, temp-tables, create-table

I am trying to create a temporary table but I keep getting open errors. g_MainDB below is my main database. When creating temporary tables do I have to use a different database or something?

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
ExecuteSQL: step failed: unable to open database file
```

I do have 2 threads which open g_MainDB but I thought that since temporary tables are not created in the main database that this wouldn't have been a problem?

Can somebody please provide me with an example of how to create a temporary table or tell me if there is a problem with the code that I am using.. or is it indeed a locking problem?

I have a the following code:

```
  sprintf( g_txSQL, "CREATE TEMP TABLE TempPlaylist (Seq INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MD5 VARCHAR)" );
  ExecuteSQL( g_txSQL );

...

BOOL ExecuteSQL( char *pszSQL )
{
  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
  int rc;

  rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( g_MainDB, pszSQL, -1, &stmt, NULL );

  if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
  {
    LogDebugf( "ExecuteSQL: prepare failed: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg( g_MainDB ) );
    return FALSE;
  }

  rc = sqlite3_step( stmt );

  if( rc != SQLITE_ROW && rc != SQLITE_DONE )
  {
    LogDebugf( "ExecuteSQL: step failed: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg( g_MainDB ) );
    sqlite3_finalize( stmt );
    return FALSE;
  }

  sqlite3_finalize( stmt );
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: check if your directory where database files resides has write access. http://www.pantz.org/software/sqlite/unabletoopendbsqliteerror.html

Comment: You can create a temporary database (rather than table) by specifying the filename as either NULL for an on-disk temporary db or ":memory" for an in-memory temporary db in the `sqlite3_open` call. That being said, I don't see the sqlite3_open call in your code that might point to issues opening the database, where is that? Are you able to create non-temp tables in the currently attached db? You might also try being explict and passing a database name of temp to the create statement by specifying the table name as `temp.TempPlaylist` as the temp database should be where this table is created.

Comment: @ssnobody: Yes, I can create non-temp tables. Thats where my journey started. I created a non-temp table but I was unable to drop the table because of it somehow becoming locked. I've checked all of my finalize calls but can't find any problems there so I thought I would give the temp table a try - since it is temporary anyway. I wouldn't mind creating a brand new database for this purpose.. but if I were to do that, can I still run SQL across tables from different databases?

Comment: @ssnobody: Sorry, can't provide the open() call at the moment - back at work now.

Comment: You can still run sql across tables from different dbs, just attach to the other dbs and in your statements qualify the tables with the db name so we have mydbname.mytablename instead of just mytablename.

Comment: @ssnobody: Cool, thanks. I may give that a go if I can't sort it out. Tonight I'll write a small PC test app to try out the temp table creation. The problem I'm having is on an Android device.. and when I copy the database file into SQLManager (Firefox), it creates temp tables no problem at all.

Comment: What OS are you using? What is the temporary directory? Can you access it?

Comment: @CL: I'm using Android - various versions of OS because I have multiple devices and they all have the same problem. I have read/write access to the main database. I have moved on and tried creating a :memory: database - similar problems there.

Comment: @ssnobody: Hi. I knocked up a test PC SQLite app that created a memory database, attached it to my main database, created a table in the memory database, dropped that table, detached - all without problem. Then I tried to do the same thing in my Android app - problems with the DROP and DETACH claiming that the main database and memory databases were locked respectively. I will try and post more code when I get more time. I suspect that the minute the memory database is attached to the main database, thats when the locking issues start.

Comment: @ssnobody: I have tried a) attaching the temp database to the main database.. and.. b) attaching the main database to the temp database. For (b) I can detach and drop the temporary table but I cannot insert into the main database because of "step failed: database is locked" all over again.